# What is the Gremlin query to get connected nodes and vertex labels in Amazon Neptune with TinkerPop3?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

Using Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin to query a node database. I need to not only get the out edges but the Vertexes that the edges connect. Here is a diagram of the database I am trying to query. The gray boxes above each node are the node IDs. The boxes on the edges are the label and the properties.

[image: Node Diagram]

I am able to use the following query (Java):

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> x = g.V("694837")
  .outE()
  .valueMap()
  .with(WithOptions.tokens);
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {label=match, p=0.69, id=6ac426c7-c7e1-8385-34f6-8f92a3d53057}, 
  {label=match, p=0.4,  id=76c426c7-c87d-ec2b-255a-a94dee636729}, 
  {label=match, p=0.44, id=6ac426c7-c91e-86a7-d4f8-f6bd9c075739}, 
  {label=match, p=0.79, id=dac426c7-c742-2d09-f7f1-a40fdc43352f}, 
  {label=match, p=0.12, id=d4c426c7-c9be-a9c0-ad12-fffed0f311b0}, 
  {label=match, p=0.03, id=46c426c7-ca5e-e4ea-fd60-695746befd84}, 
  {label=match, p=0.19, id=4cc426c7-c695-c67e-712f-85cd2b359e2f}, 
  {label=has,           id=8ec426c7-c293-0b42-30e1-56bafe0659dd}, 
  {label=is,    p=0.44, id=04c426c7-c1e1-9920-c3d7-afa9c6f6789a}, 
  {label=is,    p=0.49, id=40c426c7-c240-72d1-71f1-aaf02ba19842}
]
```

What I need is the above but with the vertex id of the connected vertices instead of the edge id.

```
[
  {label=match, p=0.69, vertex_id=39085}, 
  {label=match, p=0.4,  vertex_id=482928}, 
  {label=match, p=0.44, vertex_id=5948376}, 
  {label=match, p=0.79, vertex_id=23980}, 
  {label=match, p=0.12, vertex_id=873632}, 
  {label=match, p=0.03, vertex_id=961837}, 
  {label=match, p=0.19, vertex_id=184928}, 
  {label=has,           vertex_id=TL}, 
  {label=is,    p=0.44, vertex_id=GS}, 
  {label=is,    p=0.49, vertex_id=M}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a few ways to do this.  You can use `path().by()` to fetch the entire path and return the results in a path structure:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> x = g.V("694837")
  .outE().inV()
  .path()
       .by(
            valueMap()
            .with(WithOptions.tokens)
       );
```

Or you can use project to get a projection from each edge:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> x = g.V("694837")
  .project('edge','vertex')
       .by(outE().valueMap()
            .with(WithOptions.tokens))
       .by(outE().inV().valueMap()
            .with(WithOptions.tokens));
```

Or you can use as-labels and `select()`:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> x = g.V("694837")
    .outE().as('edge').
    .inV().as('vertex').
    .select('edge','vertex')
        .by(valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens));
```

In the end, a projection may work out the best here:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<Object, Object>> x = g.V("694837")
  .project('label','p','vertex_id')
       .by(outE().label())
       .by(outE().values('p'))
       .by(out().id());
```

The optional `p` maybe a little tricky.  Do you just not want that to exist if it is not available?  Or can you project an empty value?  If the latter, you could replace the second `by()` with `by(outE().coalesce(values('p'),constant(''))`.

Good resource for learning Gremlin here:  https://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am trying 
```
var x = g.V("694837")
                    .project("label","p","vertex_id")
                    .by(outE().label())
                    .by(coalesce(outE().values("p"),constant(""))
                    .by(out().id()));
```

```
ClassCastException: class CoalesceStep cannot be cast to class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.ByModulating (CoalesceStep and org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.ByModulating are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Comment: The code that the framework is running is public default GraphTraversal<S, E> by(final Traversal<?, ?> traversal) {
        this.asAdmin().getBytecode().addStep(Symbols.by, traversal);
        ((ByModulating) this.asAdmin().getEndStep()).modulateBy(traversal.asAdmin());
        return this;
    }

Comment: Oops.  Modified it slightly.  Move the initial `outE()` outside of the coalesce.  Edited in the response.